# How to do a RETWEET on an iPhone twitter app (MGTwitterEngine)

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, mgtwitterengine

How to do a RETWEET on an iPhone twitter app (MGTwitterEngine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this function hasn't supported in  mattgemmell / MGTwitterEngine  yet.

In the meantime, you can add that function to your current version of MGTwitterEngine by referencing this variant of MGTwitterEngine:
 [freeatnet / MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/freeatnet/MGTwitterEngine/commit/294035e5e7cde40c7d0239502ee208d872a6c1f6)

```
- (NSString *)sendRetweet:(unsigned long)updateID
{
  if (updateID == 0){
    return nil;
  }
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/retweet/%u.%@", updateID, API_FORMAT];

  return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:HTTP_POST_METHOD path:path 

                        queryParameters:nil body:nil 
                            requestType:MGTwitterUpdateSendRequest
                           responseType:MGTwitterStatus];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString *)sendRetweet:(unsigned long)updateID

{
    if (updateID == 0){

        return nil;
    }

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/retweet/%u.%@", updateID, API_FORMAT];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
        [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", updateID] forKey:@"id"];
        NSString *body = [self _queryStringWithBase:nil parameters:params prefixed:NO];


    return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:HTTP_POST_METHOD path:path 
                        queryParameters:params body:body 
                            requestType:MGTwitterUpdateSendRequest
                           responseType:MGTwitterStatus];
}
```