# Using retweeted_by API with MGTwitterEngine - keeps on returning error 404

Tags: iphone, oauth, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I'm trying to add a method to MGTwitterEngine to use twitter's retweeted_by API ( http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/:id/retweeted_by ).

Here is what I've added to MGTwitterEngine.m (all the OAuth stuff is done, the other methods inside the engine work fine)

```
-(NSString *)getUsersWhoRetweetedTweetWithID:(unsigned long)ID {

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/70482402362933249/retweeted_by.xml"];

return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:nil path:path queryParameters:nil body:nil 
                        requestType:MGTwitterUsers 
                       responseType:MGTwitterUsers];

}
```

Note: I've already included the .xml format and a status ID - just to ensure there's nothing wrong with the data I'm passing on. When I call [_engine getUsersWhoRetweetedTweetWithID:0]; from my app controller, error 404 is returned "The operation couldn't be completed. (HTTP error 404.)".

I've tried it with a parameters NSDictionary & tried changing the request & response types.

Currently, I don't make use of MGTwitterEngine to check who RTd a tweet, I just use a non OAuth'd method - however this will not return protected users who RTd a tweet.

Can anyone give me a point in the right direction - it's being driving me crazy for the past few days! I really appreciate any input :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here.....

[How to do a RETWEET on an iPhone twitter app (MGTwitterEngine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528741/how-to-do-a-retweet-on-an-iphone-twitter-app-mgtwitterengine)

MGTwitterEngine does not support re-tweet method yet .. you have to manually add the parse to MGTwitterEngine .h and .m then the call out would be [_engine sendRetweet:(unsigned Long)];

Now I am in the process of trying to determine how you call out the unsigned long...if any one else has an answer to that I would be happy to hear it myself.

Comment: It's not that I was looking for... I managed to do what I needed to do, just scrapped MPTwitterEngine completely and did it all myself