# MGTwitterEngine send retweet is not working

Tags: objective-c, mgtwitterengine

I'm using MGTwitterEngine. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528741/how-to-do-a-retweet-on-an-iphone-twitter-app-mgtwitterengine) post where shows a modification to the current version of MGTwitterEngine.

I've applied this modification and when I'm executing the method returns this:

```
2012-04-10 01:04:17.908 Otsuka On[27519:707] INFO -> retweet response: 07695198-2526-4FF4-BC46-8D39F7719836
```

But nothing happens in the timeline of the Twitter account.

The method added to TwitterEngine is:

```
- (NSString *)sendRetweet:(unsigned long)updateID
{
    if (updateID == 0){
        return nil;
    }
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/retweet/%u.%@", updateID, API_FORMAT];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", updateID] forKey:@"id"];
    NSString *body = [self _queryStringWithBase:nil parameters:params prefixed:NO];


    return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:HTTP_POST_METHOD path:path 

                        queryParameters:params body:body 
                            requestType:MGTwitterUpdateSendRequest
                           responseType:MGTwitterStatus];
}
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved the problem using NSString parameter as updateID:

```
- (NSString *)sendRetweet:(NSString *)updateID
{

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/retweet/%@.%@", updateID, API_FORMAT];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", updateID] forKey:@"id"];
    NSString *body = [self _queryStringWithBase:nil parameters:params prefixed:NO];


    return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:HTTP_POST_METHOD path:path 

                        queryParameters:params body:body 
                            requestType:MGTwitterUpdateSendRequest
                           responseType:MGTwitterStatus];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following method and it works for me:

```
- (NSString *)sendRetweet:(MGTwitterEngineID)tweetID {    
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/retweet/%llu.%@", tweetID,     API_FORMAT];

    return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:HTTP_POST_METHOD path:path 
                        queryParameters:nil body:nil 
                            requestType:MGTwitterRetweetSendRequest
                           responseType:MGTwitterStatus];
```

}

UPDATE: Yes, try to use this fork: github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

Comment: Hi! (MGTwitterEngineID)tweetID which data fills this parameter? I'm using the id field of the tweet which I want to retweet. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of MGTwitterEngine are you using? In my version the MGTwitterRetweetSendRequest enum doesn't exist.